# php file force download

Tags: php, download

When I use this code to download this image (only used for testing purposes), I open the downloaded image, and all it gives me is an error.  i tried it in chrome.  opening it with windows photo viewer, it says that it can't display the picture because it is empty??? 
here is the code:

```
<?PHP
 // Define the path to file
 $file = 'http://www.media.lonelyplanet.com/lpi/12553/12553-11/469x264.jpg';

 if(!file)
 {
     // File doesn't exist, output error
     die('file not found');
 }
 else
 {
     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: can readfile read a remote file??

Comment: Try removing the headers and see if you get an error

Comment: when i try downloading an image from my site, i get the same error.  and let me try removing the header.

Comment: so i removed the headers, and got a lot of random ascii characters

Comment: just notice that the above script has another obvious problem: `if(!file)` does not check whether the file exists or not, but checking the string exists instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a chance to work it out.  Your problem is two-fold.

First, remove the `www.` from the url.

Second, remove the call to `filesize($file)` which is throwing an error because PHP doesn't know the size of the file before it downloads the file.  (really, just remove the whole line)

Removing these two things, I was successful.

Comment: Yes, `filesize` should be used only when providing download option of local files (files at server).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `ob_clean()` with `ob_end_clean()`

You're still buffering, so none of the image contents get to the browser.

Comment: wait, I don't see you starting a buffer... Why is that ob_clean there anyway?

Comment: have you tried setting the mimetype correctly to `image/jpeg`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

With:

```
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: The url http://www.media.lonelyplanet.com/lpi/12553/12553-11/469x264.jpg doesn't seem valid to me.

Comment: it was valid when i was using it.  image: http://media.lonelyplanet.com/lpi/12553/12553-11/469x264.jpg

Comment: still didn't work, by the way, using header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

Comment: Ha. Get rid of the `www.` in your url string

Comment: so it should be like: http://media.lonelyplanet.com/lpi/12553/12553-11/469x264.jpg?  still doesn't work :p

Comment: did that fix work for you?  i have a feeling i am missing something, or overlooking something simple haha

Comment: Wrong version is still in the cache?

Comment: It is called `file_get_contents()` not `get_file_contents`

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is just the download the file from a third party on click of a link, you could use the new property download in the anchor tag.

The code will look something like

```
<a download href="path/to/the/download/file"> Clicking on this link will force download the file</a>
```

It works on firefox and chrome latest version. Should I mention that I didn't check it in IE? :P